# Evaluating Integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \ln \left(|e^{ix}-1| \right)\,dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Consider the integral $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \ln \left(|e^{ix}-1| \right)\,dx$$how do I solve this integral? I have a feeling that the answer is a multiple of $2\pi$. I have tried setting $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i \sin(x)$, which turns the integral into $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln \left(|\cos(x)+i \sin(x)-1| \right)\,dx$$ but this did not make the evaluation any easier because I am not sure what to do with the logarithm function.

Comment: $\log(|e^{ix}-1|)=\log |2\sin x/2|$ and that is a classic integral you can find on this site and other places

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/815762/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/318415/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D%20%5Cln%20%5Cleft(%7Ce%5E%7Bix%7D-1%7C%20%5Cright)%5C%2C%20dx%20%3D%200%24)

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}I&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln(|e^{ix}-1|)dx\\
\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln(|\cos(x)+i\sin(x)-1|)dx\\
\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln(\sqrt{2-2\cos x})dx\\
\\
&=\frac{1}2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln\left(4\sin^2 \frac{x}2\right)dx\\
\\
&=2\pi\ln2+\frac{1}2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln\left(\sin^2 \frac{x}2\right)dx,~~~~~~~~~x=2t\\
\\
&=2\pi\ln2+\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\left(\sin^2 t\right)dt\\
\\
&=2\pi\ln2+2\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\left(\sin t\right)dt\\
\\
&=2\pi\ln2-2\pi\ln2\\
\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

The last integral can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354795/evaluate-int-0-pi-ln-left-sin-theta-right-d-theta)